# Windows script doesn't work when user types in a whitespace

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting, spritebatch

I'm writing a Windows script in batch. I have a problem with whitespaces in variables. When the user types in a space, the script breaks.

Here's the part of my script:

```
:package
SET /P packageName="Set package name:"
IF [%packageName%] EQU [] (
   ECHO Empty package name.
   goto package
) ELSE (
    set "packageName=%packageName: =%"
    echo %packageName%
    pause
)
```

Comment: use quotes (`"`) with `if` instead of `[` and `]`

Comment: Unfortunately, this sotulion don't work.
(Syntax error)

Comment: What does not work? please describe in detail what you expect and what you actually get...

Comment: `IF "%packageName%" EQU "" (` issue a syntax error?

Comment: You should replace `[%packageName%] EQU []` with `"%packageName%"==""`. Check my answer. It works for me with and without whitespaces.

Comment: @MichaelS: Yes, exactly the same change suggested by Stephan 26 minutes ago...

Comment: I've added a second modification. Copy&paste my code. It works just fine for me!

Comment: By the way, what Stephan suggested is different from my solution. I've also replaced `EQU` with `==`. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelS: Yes, and I don't understand why you did that. `==` is the original way to do comparisons used in Batch files since 35 years ago! `EQU` and the rest of 3-letters comparison operators is the modern way to do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This schould work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:package
SET /P packageName="Set package name:"
IF "%packageName%"=="" (
   ECHO Empty package name.
   goto package
) ELSE (
    set packageName=%packageName: =%
    echo !packageName!
    pause
)
```

There are two modifications to your script:

- `[%packageName%] EQU []` was replaced with `"%packageName%"==""`
- I've added `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and changes `echo %packageName%` with `echo !packageName!`

The second point is because you are changing the value of a variable inside an IF-construction. As the interpreter doesn't know what the new value will be at "compile" time, you have to evaluate the variable at run time. That's why you need `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `!...!` instead of `%...%`. This forces the expansion at run time.

Comment: This code will not work correctly if the user just types one or more spaces

Comment: Right. But it won't work because of the replacement operation. So this was not part of the question. For this case I'd propose an additional IF-check inside the ELSE block.

Comment: And just move `set packageName=%packageName: =%` after `set /p` will be enough

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:package
rem Predefine variable packageName with a single double quote as value.
rem This value is kept if the user just hits RETURN or ENTER on prompt.
rem The single double quote is removed 2 command lines below if the user
rem does not enter anything or it is overwritten by user entered string.
set "packageName=""

set /P "packageName=Set package name: "

rem Remove double quotes from entered string. This is necessary to
rem avoid a syntax error on next command line with the IF condition.
set "packageName=!packageName:"=!"

if "!packageName!" == "" (
    echo Empty package name.
    goto package
) else (
    set "packageName=%packageName: =%"
    echo Package name with spaces:    %packageName%
    echo Package name without spaces: !packageName!
    pause
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Especially the help pages output on execution of `if /?` should be read carefully and completely as this helps explains delayed expansion as it must be used here on examples.

See also the output of the 2 **echo** lines in **ELSE** branch in code above to understand what is the difference between referencing a variable with percent signs or with exclamation marks in blocks defined with `(` ... `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is almost correct except for "variable search/replace" which its position is to be before "`IF`"

```
@echo off
:package
set /p packagename="set package name:"
set packagename=%packagename: =%
if [%packagename%] equ [] (
echo empty package name &goto package
) else (echo %packagename%)
```